# Converting syntax from Objective C to Swift ^()

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have a Swift project in which I am using a Objective C Custom Gesture Recognizer.

I have converted with success everything untill now. Can't quite figure how to convert that  **`return ^(UITableView *tableView, NSIndexPath *indexPath) { };`** Everything I've tried didn't compile.

Objective C code:

```
 typedef void(^DRCellSlideActionBlock)(UITableView *tableView, NSIndexPath *indexPath);
    typedef void(^DRCellSlideActionStateBlock)(DRCellSlideAction *action, BOOL active);




  -(void)doSomething{
            squareAction.didTriggerBlock = [self pushTriggerBlock];
    }

- (DRCellSlideActionBlock)pushTriggerBlock {

    return ^(UITableView *tableView, NSIndexPath *indexPath) {
           NSLog(@"Do Something");
        }]];

        [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
    };
}
```

What I've tried:

Error: *Consecutive statements must be separated....*

```
   return (tableView: UITableView, indexPath: NSIndexPath) in {
}
```

Also tried this as for the completion of (`UIView.animateWithDuration`) :

Error: *Consecutive statements must be separated....*

```
return () -> (tableView: UITableView, indexPath: NSIndexPath) in {
```

*By the way, I'm kinda new to Swift so excuse my code*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just look up closures' syntax in the official Swift guide? You are completely misled as to what closures look like.

```
return { (tableView: UITableView, indexPath: NSIndexPath) in
     // closure body here
}
```